# Strange image displayed under the like button

Tags: facebook

on a site I created I have added a standard like function for advertisements users made.

Whenever I use like on a product page it works fine, e.e. http://www.markt4art.nl/Advertenties/ToonProduct.php?A=101 but on a Services page it shows a weird icon, e.g. http://www.markt4art.nl/Advertenties/ToonDienst.php?A=90

Even when I delete this image from my directory Facebook still show this weird and unwanted image.
Please explain how I can fix this and (if applicable) how I can determine myself which image Facebook will use to make a thumbnail.

This is a critical errors as all facebook likes are now very wrong...

Thx for your help.

Comment: Could you add a screen shot and outline what is wrong? I don't see any difference between the like buttons on the two pages.

Comment: The problem is that when one clicks the like button on the page http://www.markt4art.nl/Advertenties/ToonDienst.php?A=90 a yellow button is shown as thumbnail, which is wrong. This problem, strangely, oes not occur on the other pages...

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose what image Facebook will use for the thumbnail.  If you don't, Facebook will just find a random image on the screen and use it.  For your first page it's using the beach picture.  For the second it's using the ugly yellow 'play' button right next to where it says "Showreel".

To specify what image should show up you need to add a meta tag to your head like this:

```
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://Your image location.jpg" />
```

More info here: http://blog.smartwebsitetips.com/75/how-to-force-facebook-choose-right-image-for-like-button/

Comment: Hi,I did this and in the head of the doc is now this code: <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Markt4Art voor al uw aankopen en verkopen van kunst</title>
<meta property='og:image' content='http://www.markt4art.nl/Images/OfferSmall/ugomcqfoptsmqxezihmrvdptsdvgrebtm.jpeg' /> but the wrong image is still shown...

Comment: What is even more weird is that when I use the debugger the debugger show the correct image...

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Please mark this question as answered.